# How check the value of multiple check boxes?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a loop which loops through and creates 4 checkboxes. However, because there is only one in the view, I cannot get the value of all 4 checkboxes. Is there a way to get all the ID's of the checkboxes and then check each ones value?

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-10" id="createButton">
    @foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleId) {
        <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.Value" class="checkbox-inline" id="test" />
        @Html.Label(item.Value, new { @class = "control-label" })
    }
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
  $("#CreateUserButton").on('click', function () {
     if ($('#test').attr('checked', false)) {
        alert("hey");
     }
  });        
</script>
```

Comment: try by class name
$(":checkbox-inline").each(function(){
alert($(this).prop('checked'));
});

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context. Your server side script is rendering invalid HTML markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to check all checkboxes

```
$(":checkbox").each(function(){
    alert($(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Comment: Hi, this works fine. However, I have multiple check boxes in the view so it checks them all. Is there a way to fix this

Comment: yes,you can assign them different class or can apply js on their parent div

Comment: Nice, thank you :) I tried it with an ID although it didnt work, strange. Works with a class though

Comment: @AndrewKilburn  cannot work with duplicate IDs using id selector. Read other comments... That's said, using attribute selector would work `$('[id=test]').prop('checked', true);` **but** don't use it, instead, render valid HTML markup

Comment: The each loop is usless here, `prop()` setter method is already iterating through matched set internally

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `id` which is getting duplicated in each iteration of the `for...each` loop. better to remove it and make a selector with class name.

```
<div class="col-md-10" id="createButton">
     @foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleId) {
       <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.Value" class="checkbox-inline test" />
       @Html.Label(item.Value, new { @class = "control-label" })
     }
</div>
```

then you can use it:

```
$("#CreateUserButton").on('click', function () {
    if ($('.test:checked').each(function() {
        console.log(this.value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like,

```
$("#CreateUserButton").on('click', function () {
    $('#createButton :checkbox').each(function(){
         console.log(this.checked);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try code given below :

```
var checked_value =[];

$('.checkbox-inline').each( function() {
    if($(this).attr('checked')) {
          checked_value.push($(this).attr('value'));
       }
});
```